# SELECT returning unexpected results because of JOIN INDEX

Tags: sql, teradata

I have defined two views AV and BV on table A and B respectively. Both views have a hardcoded column, DATATABLE in their definition. Value for DATATABLE in AV is 'TABLEA' and in BV is 'TABLEB'.

**Scenario 1:** Executing the below query:

```
    SELECT DATATABLE FROM
    ( SELECT DATATABLE, SERIAL FROM AV
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATATABLE, SERIAL FROM BV
    ) T0
    WHERE SERIAL in ('X','Y')
    GROUP BY 1
```

The expected result is:

```
    TABLEA
    TABLEB
```

The returned result by the query is:

```
    TABLEB
    NULL
```

(NULL as in Null value not string 'NULL'; displayed as '?' in teradata sql assistant)

**Scenario 2:** Executing the below query:

```
    SELECT DATATABLE,SERIAL FROM
    ( SELECT DATATABLE, SERIAL FROM AV
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATATABLE, SERIAL FROM BV
    ) T0
    WHERE SERIAL in ('X','Y')
    GROUP BY 1,2
```

The expected result is:

```
    TABLEA, X
    TABLEA, Y
    TABLEB, X
    TABLEB, Y
```

The returned result by the query is:

```
    TABLEA, NULL
    TABLEB, X
    TABLEB, Y
```

**Scenario 3:** Executing the below query:

```
    SELECT DATATABLE,COUNT(*) FROM
    ( SELECT DATATABLE, SERIAL FROM AV
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATATABLE, SERIAL FROM BV
    ) T0
    WHERE SERIAL in ('X','Y')
    GROUP BY 1
```

The expected result is:

```
    TABLEA, 100326622
    TABLEB, 18048052
```

The returned result by the query is:

```
    TABLEA, 100326622
    TABLEB, 18048052
```

**Scenario 4:** Adding few more columns or joining the query with some other table is resulting in the expected results set for the column DATATABLE i.e. value 'TABLEA' and 'TABLEB'.

When I fetched the EXPLAIN PLAN for the above four scenarios, I found out the first two scenarios are using the a JOIN INDEX (Named AJ) defined on the table A while the rest are using the table directly not the JOIN INDEX. After trying repeatedly, I figured whenever optimiser uses the JOIN INDEX AJ defined on table A instead of accessing the table directky, it results in erroneous output for the column DATATABLE.

I don't have much experience with neither Teradata not JOIN INDEX. I am unable to figure out the any further reasons behind this strange output. What is possible solution in this case?

Comment: You show expected results on queries that are not syntactically correct, throwing in doubt your entire question.  Hint:  `WHERE` does not go after `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect syntax. It must have occured while typing as I have not exactly copy+pasted the code. You can rest be assured that the codes were syntactically correct and they were executed and produced the mentioned outputs.

Comment: The optimizer is deciding that, for your smaller set of columns, the join index will cover your request, so it's using it.  Is the join index current? It's impossible to tell from for certain from your scenarios, but you probably need to refresh the join index.+

Comment: When using the Join Index returns a wrong result you probably found a bug, please open an incident with TD support. @Andrew: A JI is always current, no way/need to refresh it.